# What's a logical R function that determines if the vector is numeric

Tags: r

Suppose I had the vector:

```
      a <- c(1,2,3, "bob", "avery", "banana123", 3,4)
```

What's a function that tells me whether each of the entries in the vector is numerical or not? I tried `is.numeric` but that returns FALSE because of the non-numerical entries in the vector. I'm wondering if there's a function that would return

```
     TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: @akrun Hm, sorry for the confusion. What if I don't know what the non-numerical element in the vector is? So I could have a <- c("bob", "george", 3,4,5). In that case how can I weed out the non-numerical entries?

Comment: @Adrian It should work if this is what you wanted `grepl("[0-9]", a)# or just `grep("[0-9]", a, value=TRUE)``grep("^[0-9]$", a, value=TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun I see, but some of the non-numerical entries are say, "bob123", and using what you've suggested will return TRUE, whereas it should actually be false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say try:

```
grep("^[0-9]+$", a, value=TRUE)
#[1] "1" "2" "3" "3" "4"
```

The index would be:

```
 grepl("^[0-9]+$", a)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

#data
a <- c(1,2,3, "bob", "avery", "banana123", 3,4)
```

Using @Sven Hohenstein's data, another possibility would be:

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(test[!str_detect(test, "[^0-9.+-]")])
#[1]  1.00  2.00  3.00  0.00  2.30  0.22  0.33  3.00 -0.40
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions to determine valid numeric values:

```
test <- c(1, 2, 3, 0, 2.3, 0.22, ".33", "+3", "-.4", "a1", "1a", "aa")

grepl("^([-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+)$", test)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

as.numeric(grep("^([-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+)$", test, value = TRUE))
# [1]  1.00  2.00  3.00  0.00  2.30  0.22  0.33  3.00 -0.40
```

Answer (score 1):

A crude way is to use `as.numeric`:

```
!is.na(sapply(a, as.numeric))
    1     2     3     a     3     4 
 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE 
# Warning message:
# In lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

But you will have to ignore the warnings. The solution @akrun provided is more elegant:

```
grepl("[0-9]", a)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

To keep only the numeric entries you can use the boolean vector to subset:

```
as.numeric(a[grepl("[0-9]", a)])
[1] 1 2 3 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `%in%` on a defined range of numeric values. Here I use zero through 99.

```
> a <- c(1, 2, 3, "bob", "avery", "banana123", 3, 4)
> a %in% 0:99
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is a character string in your vector, R interprets all of the elements of the vector as characters.

```
a <- c("bob", "george", 3,4,5)
a    
[1] "bob"    "george" "3"      "4"      "5"
```

You need to use regular expressions.

Assuming that none of the true character elements (`"george"`, `bob`) contain no numbers you can just use what @akrun suggested:

```
a <- c("bob", "george", 3,4,5321.428,-7)
grepl("[0-9]", a)
 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```